# In Bash, how do I display script output and then resume to the previous output (like less, or top, or watch)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, console

I don't want to write C code for this,
But I want my script to behave like 'watch': display output on a clean console, and eventually return to the original output that was displayed.

I'm not using watch because it messes with my output and lack functions I want to add.

Regular 'clear' will fill up my console with pages and pages of the same output and I want to avoid that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just found that: echo -e '\033[0;0Htop left corner, overwriting old output' so this could reduce the output of the script to a single screen.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal curses software such as ncurses should work as well as making 'q' to quit like `less` fairly simple